# Firestore Angular integration error: Firestore has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just set up firebase in my angular project. I have a problem while trying to use a firestore function.
I have this service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Firestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {
  doc,
  getDoc,
} from 'firebase/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FirestoreService {  
  constructor(public firestore: Firestore) {}

  async getCollection() {
    const docRef = doc(this.firestore, 'teams', 'pippo');
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      console.log('Document data:', docSnap.data());
    } else {
      // docSnap.data() will be undefined in this case
      console.log('No such document!');
    }
  }
}
```

If I try to run this function from the code, let's say, from a button event, everything works fine, but if I put this code inside my app.component.ts ngOnInit(), the page recharge on my browser never stops recharging, and if I stop the refresh and try to start it manually I get this error:

> Firestore has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only modify settings before calling any other methods on a Firestore object.

I don't understand this error. But if I try to put the code of getCollection directly inside of my ngOnInit function, everything works fine again

[EDIT]
I tried to use the same functions in a new angular project and everything works fine (after all it wasn’t the first time I used it in an angular project).
At this point I think it’s a problem of configurations and libraries installation. Some suggestion about how to clean delete firebase and reinstall everything?

Comment: Have you tried doing a web search for that exact error message?  There is a lot to read about it that might be helpful.  You might want to focus more on where you are initializing Firebase rather than the code you show here.

Comment: I’m initializing it in my app.module. The error says I’m trying to change the settings but I actually don’t. At least not intentionally!